# Would or would have

Tags: meaning-in-context, grammar

Are those sentences correctly?

> If you only were able to go back to the 90s you would have dated him.

Can this sentence be treated as mixed conditional?

> Sorry but it looks like you wouldn't have cared about him when he was ill.

Answer (score 0):

The first sentence states that it is not possible to go back the 1990s, but if it was, dating some other person would also be possible.

Since we're stating a possibility, *could* is more useful than *would*, which is based on desire, and *were able to*, which means the same thing [as *could*]:

> If only you **could** go back to the 90s and date him.

To me, there are a couple of things wrong with the second sentence:

- There should be a comma after *sorry*, as the speaker would generally pause there.
- It feels more natural for the negative to come first, though not doing so is still completely acceptable.
- *Cared* is spelled incorrectly.
- *When* should be replaced by *while*, as he was ill for a duration of time and someone didn't care about him (possibly) for that duration.

The following sentence contains these additions:

> Sorry, but it doesn't look like you would have cared about him while he was ill.